# docusign template custom field not being filled

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to get the custom fields that I have added to my template to be filled with the values I am sending in the xml request document.  I am positive it is an obvious mistake, but I am just not seeing it.  I also see this question askd a couple other times without an answer.  this is my request.  I can sign the document, but non of the non standard fields are filled.

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <status>sent</status>
    <emailSubject>Disclosuresave - Clue Authorization Form</emailSubject>
    <templateId>x</templateId>
    <templateRoles>
        <templateRole>
            <email>test@test.test</email>
            <name>test name</name>
            <roleName>Recipient</roleName>
            <clientUserId>####</clientUserId>
            <CustomFields>
                <CustomField>
                    <Name>Address</Name>
                    <Show>True</Show>
                    <Required>False</Required>
                    <Value>123 Ash St</Value>
                </CustomField>
                <CustomField>
                    <Name>City</Name>
                    <Show>True</Show>
                    <Required>False</Required>
                    <Value>Beverly Hills</Value>
                </CustomField>
            </CustomFields>
        </templateRole>
    </templateRoles>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the fields that you're trying to fill are data fields that you've placed on the documents within the Template, then these aren't "custom fields" -- they're "tabs".  If that's your scenario, then the tabs portion of your request should look like this:

```
<tabs>
    <textTabs>
        <text>
            <name>Address</name>
            <value>123 Ash St</value>
        </text>
        <text>
            <name>City</name>
            <value>Beverly Hills</value>
        </text>
    </textTabs>
</tabs>
```

Also, do note that element names are case-sensitive (i.e., "name" not "Name", "value" not "Value", etc.) -- AND, the value of the **name** element for each tab is case-sensitive as well. For example, if the Template defines the tab label as *City* but your API request sets **name** = *city*, then the API request won't populate that field in the Envelope (because *City* != *city*).

For future reference, this online resource contains details about request/response formats for all REST API operations in both JSON and XML:  https://www.docusign.net/restapi/help.