# docusign template custom field not being filled by API

Tags: json, docusignapi

Im trying to fill some custom fields on my template. And send the value of the custom field on the JSON.

So what I did is this:

- Log in to https://appdemo.docusign.com

  1. Edit my template.
  2. Go to custom field tab
  3. click on plus button
  4. Create a custom field named: 'Custom'
  5. Drag the field on my template
  6. Save & Close

[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdlYw.png)

Now, using the api Im try to create an envalope with this template.

According to one question that I found:

```
      If the fields that you're trying to fill are data fields that
     you've placed on the 
documents within the Template, then these aren't "custom fields" -- they're "tabs".
```

[docusign template custom field not being filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315691/docusign-template-custom-field-not-being-filled)

So for create an envalope Im sending this json:

```
{

  "emailSubject":"This is a DocuSign Test from Mauricio",

  "status":"sent",

  "templateId":"a0847413-35ac-48ed-9ed6-9b7f96019eda",

  "templateRoles":[
    {

      "email":"mtaranto@test12.com",

      "name":"Mauricio Taranto",

      "roleName":"Test",

      "routingOrder":"1",

       "tabs": {

        "textTabs": [

          {

            "name": "Custom",

            "value": "This is a custom value"

          }

        ]

      }

    }

  ],

  }
```

I dont have any issues on the creation in terms of the api response. I get the email and also the name field and email name get filed on the PDF.

But the custom field I added to the template does not populate.

The square under my email is the custom field (see the image.)

[PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jND0d.png)

What Im doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the "tabLabel" parameter instead of the "name" parameter for your tag names. Everything else looks correct.

As a side note, the [API docs say](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Automatically%20Populating%20Tabs.htm) if you're going to have the same tag more than once on the document, you'll want to add `\\*` before the tag's name so that all are populated.

Changing your example to this should work:

```
{
    "emailSubject": "This is a DocuSign Test from Mauricio",
    "status": "sent",
    "templateId": "a0847413-35ac-48ed-9ed6-9b7f96019eda",
    "templateRoles": [{
        "email": "mtaranto@test12.com",
        "name": "Mauricio Taranto",
        "roleName": "Test",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "tabs": {
            "textTabs": [{
                "tabLabel": "\\*Custom",
                "value": "This is a custom value"
            }]
        }
    }],

}
```